# Uploading schema.xml on zookeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am trying to update schema.xml which is there on zookeeper instance(Standalone),
I have all the config files namely solr.xml, managed-schema, and zoo.cfg.
I am using the below command 
"./zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost  IP-zookeeper:2181  -collection cloudsolr -confname cloudconf -confdir /opt/solr-7.0.0/server/solr/node1/solr/conf" 
when i run the command from solr/server/scripts/cloudscripts, it runs ok, but when i log in to the solr homepage in the managed-schema file i am seeing the older one only no updates happened. Please help me out, idk where m going wrong.

Comment: Forgot to mention i restarted solr instances, but still its the same

Comment: If you're using the managed schema (which it sounds like you are, since you have the managed schema directory), the old schema.xml is never read. [You have to switch to the ClassicIndexSchemaFactory in that case first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988999/solr-managed-schema-how-to-use-it/39989727#39989727).

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you, i still have a couple of doubts, i was running solr not in a standalone mode, i was using managed-schema to index the document now i am migrating to solr cluster on different machines, so i am trying to use to same schema file because the data is same. So can i use to same managed-schema or do i have to do something else? I am new to solrcloud so lots of doubt, but kindly help.

Comment: I think i got it sorted out, Thank you @MatsLindh