# How can I search the special characters in Solr

Tags: search, solr, special-characters, highlight

I'm used Solr 6.6.2

I need to search the special characters and highlight it in Solr,

But it does not work,

my data :

```
[
    {
     "id" : "test1",
     "title" : "test1# title C# ",
     "dynamic_s": 5
    },
    {
     "id" : "test2",
     "title" : "test2 title C#",
     "dynamic_s": 10
    },
    {
     "id" : "test3",
     "title" : "test3 title",
     "dynamic_s": 0
    }
]
```

When I search "C#",

Then it will just response like this "test1# title *C*# ",

It just highlights "C" this word...and "#" will not searching and highlight.

How can I make the search and highlight work for special characters?

Comment: What is the definition of the field `title`?

Comment: It's text_general <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StandardTokenizer splits tokens on special characters, meaning that `#` will split the content into separate tokens - the first token will be `C` - and that's what's being highlighted. You'll probably get the exact same result if you just search for C.

The tokenization process will make your tokens end up being `test2` `title` `C` .

Using a field type with a [WhitespaceTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-WhiteSpaceTokenizer) that only splits on whitespace will probably be a better choice for this exact use case, but it's impossible to say if that'll be a good match for your regular search behavior (i.e. if you actually want to match 'C' to `C-99' etc., splitting by those characters can be needed). But - you can use a specific field for highlighting, and that fields analysis chain will be used to determine what to highlight. And you can ask for both the original and the more specific field to be highlighted, and then use the best result in your frontend application.

Comment: I try to set the fieldtype to this     
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
But i still not work
and I also need LowerCase on index and search but it will clear the special characters, how can i fix it?

Comment: You'll add a filter for lowercase-ing (see the old `text_general` definition)- and I strongly suggest defining it as a differently named field type instead of changing `text_general`. You will also have to reindex after changing the definition, and there is no need to define both `query` and `index` if the definitions are identical, just define them directly under `fieldType`.

Comment: If you copy the definition for text_general and just change the tokenizer, reindex and it should work.

Comment: I know how to add filter for lowercase, but I mine if I use this filter it will make whitespace and non-letters are discarded

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. A whitespace tokenizer will break each word separate by _whitespace_ into separate tokens. There is nothing being discarded, except for the whitespace between tokens. It will still be present in the stored text. The StandardTokenizer breaks on - and removes - special characters, which is why you have to use a different tokenizer.

Comment: I do everything you say, but it's still not work, I've modify the fieldtype below

Comment: <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true"><analyzer type="index"><tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="java" /><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /></analyzer><analyzer type="query"><tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="java" /><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /><filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/></analyzer> </fieldType>
this is right?

Comment: Neither of those contain a lowercasefilter (which you wanted), and you should really name the fieldtype something else. You also have to reindex your content after changing the definition.

Comment: i know how to do the lowercasefilter, now I just need make special characters to searching, i has definition the field type and reindex, but it still not work.....

Comment: I try to definition new fieldtype for special characters search here
 <fieldType name="text_test" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="java" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="java" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

Comment: it's work.... 6.6.2 not support schema.xml need use managed-schema.....  Thank you

Comment: 6.6.2 supports schema.xml, you just have to tell Solr to use the [ClassicIndexSchemaFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988999/solr-managed-schema-how-to-use-it/39989727#39989727).

Comment: This issue has been fixed, but when I used WhitespaceTokenizerFactory I can't use URL add a parameter like http://tw-search01d:8866/solr/Test1/select?defType=dismax&hl.fl=title&hl=on&indent=on&q=%22C#"&qf=title^100&wt=json, If I put the q to URL, it will no result it's different to post parameter like below

Comment: {"params":{"q":"C#","defType":"dismax", "hl":"on", "indent":"on","qf":"title^100", "hl.fl":"title","wt":"json"}} if I use this json and post to query Solr I will get the result I want, but if put the parameter to URL it will no result

Comment: If you're going to use `c#` in an URL, you'll have to escape `#` (as `%23`) - since the hash sign is used to indicate a local anchor in the text and is never sent to the server. Before you've just searched for `C` (and your client has cut the URL off) and not for `C#`, but since you used the Standard Tokenizer, the indexed content was `C` anyway so it worked.

Comment: Is it only have # need to escape? does have any outs special characters need to escape?

Comment: There are many characters that have special meanings in URLs, and your programming language of choice [probably have a dedicated function for escaping values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) used in URLs. In Javascript (so if you press F12 and bring up the console) you can use `encodeURIComponent` to get the encoded version of a value back so that it's safe to use as a value in a URL argument string.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh one more question, If I need use make a Chinese word to spile e.g: "大家好"  I need to analysis to: "大","家","好"  how can I to it?

Comment: Can I use StandardTokenizerFactory and keep special characters? make special characters to index and search?